# App Store download disappear after the installation

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm trying to download a previously purchased item from the app store. The item download and install seems that works fine, but immediately after the installation the program just disappears.

The App Store app shows the Open button, but, of course do nothing. After restarting the App Store app, recognise aText as not installed and display the button Install.

What can I do to install it?

Comment: Can you find it in /Library/Receipts or ~/Library/Receipts ?

Comment: @Tetsujin nop, not there.

Comment: ah, maybe in /private/var/db/receipts - but I wouldn't be sure what to do with it if you found it in there [or grab EasyFind from the App Store & see if that can find anything - that's what I use to search in the 'hidden' structures]

Answer (score 2):

I took @Tetsujin comment and solved this by deleting all files related to the App I was trying to install. EasyFind is an easy way to find hidden files. Otherwise you can use the search in the finder, but that requires several steps.

Then I deleted all library files and the App itself was sitting in some `ApplicationSupport` directory, together with a Zip file. I deleted the whole App folder (Kaleidoscope in my case) which resided inside of the `ApplicationSupport` directory.